# Contents of Attribute - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pick up the price attribute in the below html:

```
<html><body><p>[<meta content="60.00" itemprop="price"/>]</p></body></html>
```

I am using the beautifulsoup library in python3.

Below is my current code. However i have tried many iterations of things using the docs.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(price), 'lxml')
for element in soup.find_all():
            print(element ["content"])
```

Currently the above code just prints out the same html line again.

The result i am trying to achieve is using the `'content'` attribute, which isn't always `'content'` but in this case it is, and retrieving the value of `60.00`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc ="""<html><body><p>[<meta content="60.00" itemprop="price"/>]</p></body></html>"""

soup= BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
price = soup.find("p").meta['content']

print(price)
```

Output will be:

```
60.00
```

Answer (score 0):

since your `<meta content="60.00" itemprop="price"/>` not containing any other decimal value, you can use this code :)

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<html><body><p>[<meta content="60.00" itemprop="price"/>]</p></body></html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
x = soup.findAll(name = 'meta')
print(re.sub('[^0-9,.]', '', str(x)))
```

Output will be : `60.00`